# Catching connection errors and alike when web scraping

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, error-handling

I am trying to use the following code below to try and catch connection errors and what not when I am web scraping. I basically would like to run the code and leave it to do its thing until done so if it gets one of the following errors it just sleeps then tries again. I appreciate that the code isnt exactly replicable but it doesnt always happen sometimes I can run the code which scrapes a few thousand web pages and there will be no errors at all. Other times I have to keep manually starting it again and again. I think originally I borrowed the exceptions from this site but I cant remember where.

I was just wondering why the errors are not being caught and instead crashing my code instead of closing down the webdriver recording that the link was broken for another part of my code to start a new webdriver using selenium.

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002179EB75DC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=51368): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/c793ca5f1c29af6f63ab217cbf01aa80/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002179EB75DC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

        try:
            inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('id_num')
            inputElement.send_keys(id)
            time.sleep(.3)
            inputElement.submit()
            time.sleep(.3)

        except ConnectionError as e:
            print(str(e))
            print("********Portal New connection timed out***********")
            time.sleep(30)
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            link_broken = True
            break
        except ConnectionRefusedError as e:
            time.sleep(30)
            print(str(e))
            print("*********Portal Connection refused by the server**********")
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            link_broken = True
            break
        except urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError as e:
            print(str(e))
            print("********Portal New connection timed out***********")
            time.sleep(30)
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            link_broken = True
            break
        except urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError as e:
            print(str(e))
            time.sleep(30)
            print("*********Portal Max tries exceeded************")
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            link_broken = True
            break
        except urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError as e:
            time.sleep(10)
            print("**********Timeout error************")
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
            link_broken = True
            break
```